# strange thing in ui update from another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm developing a vb.net application who needs to do lot of background work.I have one thread different from the main thread where I visit an url to login to a website and when it finish I want to change the text of a label.I have added in the main form this (I know that is a quick code,but it's worked me very well in other applications)

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

I also have tried the invoke method but same result.
The threads are in another class that it isn't the main form class,but if a thread is in the main form class it works and if it is in another class doesn't work

Thanks

EDIT:
I have just tried this:

```
Public Sub UpdateButton(ByVal objs() As Object)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Object())(AddressOf UpdateButton), objs)
        Return
    End If
    CType(objs(0), Button).Text = objs(1).ToString
End Sub
```

EDIT 2:

New change no success

```
  Public Sub UpdateButton(ByVal objs As List(Of Object))
    If CType(objs(0), Button).InvokeRequired Then
        CType(objs(0), Button).Invoke(New Action(Of List(Of Object))(AddressOf UpdateButton), objs)
        Return
    End If
    CType(objs(0), Button).Text = objs(1).ToString
End Sub
```

I have changed it because it gave me an error with number of elements

EDIT 3:I have seen that I haven't explained well.

I got A form called Form1 and a Module called Functions.In the module functions I defined the four threads that my application has and its functions and  two functions per thread start[thread name] and stop[thread name] where I start and stop the thread.Then I put a button in the form1 and when the users clicks it calls the start function of the thread I assgined.For exameple my application has got a thread called session_starter so when the user clicks in the login button I call startSession from the button and when it finish,the last line of the function of the thread calls updatebutton from form1 and when I call it changes the text of the button,but to 0.

I have made the updatebutton the most generally possible because I got lots of button (about 30!!) and making a function for every button change is a bit slow and annoying

EDIT 4:
I have made some experiments.I put a button in the Form1 and this code to the button:

```
Private Sub Button10_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    Button9.Text = "hi"
    Dim Evaluator = New Thread(Sub() Me.UpdateButton(Button9, "test"))
    MsgBox("Text after setting from another thread: " & Button9.Text)
    UpdateButton(Button9, "test")
    MsgBox("Text after setting from ui thread: " & Button9.Text)
End Sub
```

And this is what I got:
Text after setting from another thread: hi
Text after setting from ui thread: test

I don't know why it happens.The code i have used is this:

```
 Public Sub UpdateButton(ByVal btn As Button, ByVal str As String)
    If btn.InvokeRequired Then
        btn.Invoke(New Action(Of Button, String)(AddressOf UpdateButton), btn, str)
        Return
    End If
    btn.Text = str
End Sub
```

Comment: That code above does not make cross thread calls legal. Show the code you are trying.

Comment: Before the thread ends I do this: Form1.Button3.Text = "Logged In" then the threads end

Comment: That code makes no sense to me. Please explain what you are trying to do. You don't need a thread to change text on a button???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple cross thread updating:

```
Public Sub UpdateButton(btn As Button, text As String)
  btn.Text = text
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
'from other thread
 Me.Invoke(Sub() 
             UpdateButton(Button9, "some text")
           End Sub)
```

Comment: Tried it and gave me invalid operation exception.I only added   CType(objs(0), Button).Text = objs(1).ToString

Comment: Can you show how your calling that method? How are you threading?

Comment: Form1.UpdateButtonTest({Form1.Button9, "Test"})

Comment: Why are you using this calling convention? Are you calling form1 from a diff form?

Comment: Show us the code that invokes the new thread that is calling this `UpdateButton` method.

Comment: It is to convert the object 0 to a button and object 1 to string

Comment: I know what your trying to do in the code provided. I want to see where you initiate a thread and how it calls the `UpdateButton` method.

Comment: I initiate the thread when the user clicks in the button,in the start function I put this:     Public Sub startSessions()
        session_thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ss)
        session_thread.Start()
    End Sub

Comment: Your thread cannot assign a button to that sub - that is where the exception comes from, not the in the UpdateButton method.

Comment: What?The code I have posted above is the assign of the thread.The functions that has the updatebutton is ss

Comment: When your thread calls `UpdateButton(Button9,"some text")` it cannot access `Button9` since it is not on the `UI` thread - that is the error.

Comment: I know that it was calling from another thread that it isn't ui thread.What I want is to change the text of the button from another thread that it isn't ui thread

Comment: It doesn't work in the module.I can't use Me in the module.If I replace Me with Form1 I got the same error:Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Comment: That is a problem! Why is it in a module? Just keep it in the class.

Comment: The reason no one can answer your question is you cannot give us all the info from the start - why is that?

Comment: OK.I put it in a module because the module has got too many lines to put in the same file of the form that also has got too many lines (+1000 lines each file)

Comment: I have a thread declared in the module and addressed to a function called ss.SS is a function that has a while loop ands calls a function that log in my website some accounts and when it finish I want to change the text of the button9 in the main form to say that the proccess has ended.This is what I only want to do

Comment: I have several files that are 6000+ lines of code - ever hear of `Regions`?

Comment: The module is the wrong way to go here, I can't help you further.

Comment: Yes,I use Regions in the module.I will change it to a class

Comment: Finally I merged the two files.Now it is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly update the UI from a different thread than it was created on.

[How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> > Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other thread-related bugs are possible as well, including race conditions and deadlocks. It is important to ensure that access to your controls is done in a thread-safe way.
> >
> > The .NET Framework helps you detect when you are accessing your controls in a manner that is not thread safe. When you are running your application in the debugger, and a thread other than the one which created a control attempts to call that control, the debugger raises an InvalidOperationException with the message, "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

[You will have to use the `Invoke` method on the control to update the UI control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The code below is from the link above.

```
' The following example demonstrates the 'Invoke(Delegate)' method of 'Control class. 
' A 'ListBox' and a 'Button' control are added to a form, containing a delegate 
' which encapsulates a method that adds items to the listbox.This function is executed 
' on the thread that owns the underlying handle of the form. When user clicks on button 
' the above delegate is executed using 'Invoke' method. 

Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Threading

Public Class MyFormControl
   Inherits Form

   Delegate Sub AddListItem()
   Public myDelegate As AddListItem
   Private myButton As Button
   Private myThread As Thread
   Private myListBox As ListBox

   Public Sub New()
      myButton = New Button()
      myListBox = New ListBox()
      myButton.Location = New Point(72, 160)
      myButton.Size = New Size(152, 32)
      myButton.TabIndex = 1
      myButton.Text = "Add items in list box" 
      AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
      myListBox.Location = New Point(48, 32)
      myListBox.Name = "myListBox"
      myListBox.Size = New Size(200, 95)
      myListBox.TabIndex = 2
      ClientSize = New Size(292, 273)
      Controls.AddRange(New Control() {myListBox, myButton})
      Text = " 'Control_Invoke' example"
      myDelegate = New AddListItem(AddressOf AddListItemMethod)
   End Sub 'New 

   Shared Sub Main()
      Dim myForm As New MyFormControl()
      myForm.ShowDialog()
   End Sub 'Main

   Public Sub AddListItemMethod()
      Dim myItem As String 
      Dim i As Integer 
      For i = 1 To 5
         myItem = "MyListItem" + i.ToString()
         myListBox.Items.Add(myItem)
         myListBox.Update()
         Thread.Sleep(300)
      Next i
   End Sub 'AddListItemMethod

   Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      myThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ThreadFunction))
      myThread.Start()
   End Sub 'Button_Click

   Private Sub ThreadFunction()
      Dim myThreadClassObject As New MyThreadClass(Me)
      myThreadClassObject.Run()
   End Sub 'ThreadFunction
End Class 'MyFormControl


' The following code assumes a 'ListBox' and a 'Button' control are added to a form,  
' containing a delegate which encapsulates a method that adds items to the listbox. 
Public Class MyThreadClass
   Private myFormControl1 As MyFormControl

   Public Sub New(myForm As MyFormControl)
      myFormControl1 = myForm
   End Sub 'New 

   Public Sub Run()
      ' Execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns 
      ' 'myFormControl1' control's underlying window handle.
      myFormControl1.Invoke(myFormControl1.myDelegate)
   End Sub 'Run

End Class 'MyThreadClass
```

Comment: Thanks.But I said that I have tried this and no success

Comment: Please post your code of what you have tried so I can tailor the answer to your situation.

Comment: I have deleted it from my code some days ago,Now I am using what I have said above: In form1_load Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False and then in the thread Form1.Button3.Text = "Logged in"

Comment: As others have said, that does not prevent the cross threaded call from being illegal. It only stops the error from being thrown, not occurring.

Comment: See first message I have updated it with a new code that I have tried

Comment: Replace the ``Me.`` with the name of the button. That should fix you up.

Comment: I replaced it and no success

Comment: I was changing the text to another button xD.But it changes the text to 0